# Sdf Joint not connecting parent model to included model

Tags: joint, include, gazebo-model, ignition-fortress

for the past month I've been working in an ignition gazebo simulation using SDF file to describe my robot model. Since the robot has some repeated parts I created a different file and included it in the main model of the robot.

The problem is that, although the file is loaded in the simulation there is no joint connection between the main body and the part, collapsing the model if I give some joint command.

I also observed that if I display the joint frames of the robot in gazebo, the joint that connects the main body to the included part is missing. But it is listed in the Entity Component Manager.

If I write the robot in one single file it works perfectly, but I would like to use included files to facilitate any debug and modification process.

Here's an example code:

-> robot.sdf

```
<model name='robot' canonical_link='chassis'>
<self_colide>true</self_colide> 
<link name='chassis'>

    <visual name='visual'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
            <box>
                <size>0.4 0.3 0.04</size>
            </box>
        </geometry>

        <material>
            <ambient>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</ambient>
            <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
            <specular>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</specular>
        </material>
    </visual>
</link>

<frame name='FR_mount'>
    <pose relative_to="chassis">0.14 -0.166 -0.043 0 0 3.1415</pose>
</frame>

<include>
    <name>front_right_motor</name>
    <placement_frame>motor_mount</placement_frame>
    <pose relative_to='FR_mount'/>
    <uri>include://models/steer_wheel</uri>
</include>

<joint name='FR_motor_joint' type='revolute'>
    <parent>FR_mount</parent>
    <child>front_right_motor::motor_mount</child>
    <axis>
        <xyz expressed_in='__model__'>0 0 1</xyz> 
    </axis>
    <limit>
        <lower>-1.5708</lower>    
        <upper>1.5708</upper>     
    </limit>
</joint>
```

-> part.sdf

```
<model name="steer_wheel" canonical_link="motor">

<frame name='motor_mount'/>

<link name='motor'>
    <visual name='visual'>
        <geometry>
            <box>
                <size>0.04 0.04 0.1</size>
            </box>
        </geometry>

        <material>
            <ambient>0.1 0.1 0.1 1</ambient>
            <diffuse>0.1 0.1 0.1 1</diffuse>
            <specular>0.1 0.1 0.1 1</specular>
        </material>
    </visual>
</link>

<link name="wheel">
    <pose relative_to="motor">0 -0.03 -0.03 1.5808 0 0</pose>

    <visual name='visual'>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder>
                <radius>0.04</radius>
                <length>0.02</length>
            </cylinder>
        </geometry>

        <material>
            <ambient>0.9 0.8 0.2 1</ambient>
            <diffuse>0.9 0.8 0.2 1</diffuse>
            <specular>0.9 0.8 0.2 1</specular>
        </material>
    </visual>
</link>

<joint name='wheel_joint' type='revolute'>
    <pose relative_to='wheel'/>
    <parent>motor</parent>
    <child>wheel</child>
    <axis>
        <xyz expressed_in='__model__'>0 1 0</xyz> 
    </axis>
    <limit>
        <lower>-1.79769e+308</lower>    
        <upper>1.79769e+308</upper>     
    </limit>
</joint>
```

Here's what gazebo displays when I ask to show the joint frames:
[image: Robot's joint view]

Comment: Model composition is a fairly new feature in Gazebo. What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Gazebo Fortress 6.15.0 and sdf 1.8

Comment: Do you see any errors when running Gazebo with `-v4`?

Comment: Only this when I ask gazebo to display the joint frames, but I believe it's unrelated:
[GUI] [Err] [MeshDescriptor.cc:56] Mesh manager can't find mesh named [arrow_rotation]
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2MeshFactory.cc:562] Cannot load null mesh [arrow_rotation]
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2MeshFactory.cc:125] Failed to get Ogre item for [arrow_rotation]

Comment: And also this warnings:
[GUI] [Wrn] [Model.hh:49] Unable to serialize sdf::Model
[GUI] [Wrn] [Component.hh:144] Trying to serialize component with data type [N3sdf3v125WorldE], which doesn't have `operator<<`. Component will not be serialized.

Comment: But both of them also show in the single file version, that works correctly